# Using std::string in ImGui::InputText(...)

Tags: c++, imgui

The call to `ImGui::InputText()` takes a `char` array which I need to initialise from a `std::string` and then transfer the contents back to the `std::string`. In it's simplest form:

```cpp
char buf[255]{};
std::string s{"foo"};
void fn() {    
    strncpy( buf, s.c_str(), sizeof(buf)-1 );
    ImGui::InputText( "Text", buf, sizeof(buf) );
    s=buf;
}
```

However, it appears wasteful to have two buffers (`buf` and the buffer allocated within `std::string`) both doing much the same thing. Can I avoid the `buf` buffer and the copying to and from it by using just the `std::string` and a simple wrapper "X".
I don't care about efficiency, I just want the simplest code at the call site.
This code does work but is it safe and is there a better way?

```cpp
class X {
public:
    X(std::string& s) : s_{s} { s.resize(len_); }
    ~X() { s_.resize(strlen(s_.c_str())); }
    operator char*(){ return s_.data(); }
    static constexpr auto len() { return len_-1; }
private:
    std::string& s_;
    static constexpr auto len_=255;
};

std::string s{"foo"};

void fn() {
    ImGui::InputText( "Text", X(s), X::len() );
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use `InputText()` with `std::string` or any custom dynamic string type, see misc/cpp/imgui_stdlib.h and comments in imgui_demo.cpp.

**misc/cpp/imgui_stdlib.h**

```
namespace ImGui
{
    // ImGui::InputText() with std::string
    // Because text input needs dynamic resizing, we need to setup a callback to grow the capacity
    IMGUI_API bool  InputText(const char* label, std::string* str, ImGuiInputTextFlags flags = 0, ImGuiInputTextCallback callback = NULL, void* user_data = NULL);
    IMGUI_API bool  InputTextMultiline(const char* label, std::string* str, const ImVec2& size = ImVec2(0, 0), ImGuiInputTextFlags flags = 0, ImGuiInputTextCallback callback = NULL, void* user_data = NULL);
    IMGUI_API bool  InputTextWithHint(const char* label, const char* hint, std::string* str, ImGuiInputTextFlags flags = 0, ImGuiInputTextCallback callback = NULL, void* user_data = NULL);
}
```

Your first code

```
std::string s{"foo"};
void fn() {    
    ImGui::InputText( "Text", &s );
}
```

Reading manuals works wonders.

Comment: imgui_demo.cpp several times has the comment: "To wire InputText() with std::string or any other custom string type, see the "Text Input > Resize Callback" section of this demo, and the misc/cpp/imgui_stdlib.h file". Again, reading manuals works wonders.

Comment: Do you have a link to this wonderful manual? (not only example code)

Comment: You can get a lot from the ImGui demo that showcases most functionality with good code comments explaining things.
https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/imgui_demo.cpp

Comment: I tried this, but the IDE show a error, because the InputText second argument don't support strings

Comment: @DazzRick The second parameter is a pointer to a string.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it shows a error inside the Visual Studio too. I see the code from demo, and that show me a way that works without exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Was hapening this same exception in my program. My path was this:

1° - I use the same line from **imgui_stdlib.h**:

```cpp
IMGUI_API bool  InputText(const char* label, std::string* str, ImGuiInputTextFlags flags = 0, ImGuiInputTextCallback callback = NULL, void* user_data = NULL);
# A lot of exceptions.
```

2° I change the arguments to real variables;
3° I only use the normal constructor:

```cpp
std::string s{"example"};
void startInput() {    
    ImGui::InputText( "Text", &s );
}
#"std::string *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"
```

4° The content in the file [**imgui_demo.cpp**](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/imgui_demo.cpp#L1618):

```cpp
struct Funcs
            {
                static int MyResizeCallback(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data)
                {
                    if (data->EventFlag == ImGuiInputTextFlags_CallbackResize)
                    {
                        ImVector<char>* my_str = (ImVector<char>*)data->UserData;
                        IM_ASSERT(my_str->begin() == data->Buf);
                        my_str->resize(data->BufSize); // NB: On resizing calls, generally data->BufSize == data->BufTextLen + 1
                        data->Buf = my_str->begin();
                    }
                    return 0;
                }

                // Note: Because ImGui:: is a namespace you would typically add your own function into the namespace.
                // For example, you code may declare a function 'ImGui::InputText(const char* label, MyString* my_str)'
                static bool MyInputTextMultiline(const char* label, ImVector<char>* my_str, const ImVec2& size = ImVec2(0, 0), ImGuiInputTextFlags flags = 0)
                {
                    IM_ASSERT((flags & ImGuiInputTextFlags_CallbackResize) == 0);
                    return ImGui::InputTextMultiline(label, my_str->begin(), (size_t)my_str->size(), size, flags | ImGuiInputTextFlags_CallbackResize, Funcs::MyResizeCallback, (void*)my_str);
                }
            };

            // For this demo we are using ImVector as a string container.
            // Note that because we need to store a terminating zero character, our size/capacity are 1 more
            // than usually reported by a typical string class.
            static ImVector<char> my_str;
            if (my_str.empty())
                my_str.push_back(0);
            Funcs::MyInputTextMultiline("##MyStr", &my_str, ImVec2(-FLT_MIN, ImGui::GetTextLineHeight() * 16));
# It works without errors;
```

The last code works successfully, but you will need a way to convert the ImVector to a string. This will convert:

```cpp
std::string ImVectorToString(ImVector<char> vec) {
    std::string str;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        str += vec[i];
    }
    return str;
}
```