# C++ how to get the first and the last element in an std::vector by its base memory address

Tags: c++, reflection, static, stdvector

To me, a vector layout looks something like this:

```
struct MyViewOnHowVectorLooksLike
{
public:
   int* _first, * _last, * _end;
};
```

Known Parameters:

1. Address of the `std::vector<Type>` object
2. size of the `<Type>`

Questions:

1. Find the address of the first element and the last element in the vector

Is there any way to access the first and last elements in a `std::vector` by its base memory address, which is `&Test` in the above test case, not by calling any build-in method of the `std::vector` function eg `[0]`, `.front()`, etc; (The reason why I'm doing this is to have a static reflection system which could output the content of any given written vector type)

```
struct FTestData {
    int data;
};

class TestClass {
public:
    // test array
    std::vector<FTestData> testArray;

    TestClass(){}
};

// TEST CASE
FTestData testCon1 = FTestData();
testCon1.data = 111;
FTestData testCon2 = FTestData();
testCon2.data = 222;

TestClass Test = TestClass();
Test.testArray.push_back(testCon1);
Test.testArray.push_back(testCon2);

std::vector<FTestData>* TestData = (std::vector<FTestData>*)((size_t)&Test);
size_t ptr = (size_t)TestData;
FTestData& TestElement1 = (*TestData)[0];
size_t realFirstElementAddress = (size_t)&TestElement1;

// try to get the address of the first element in the vector but it  gives me the wrong address
size_t CustomFirstElementAddress = (*(size_t*)(ptr));

// expecting those two to be the same but it wasnt
assert(realFirstElementAddress == CustomFirstElementAddress);
```

I thought the `_First` and `_Last` are right next to the base address, but it keeps outputting the wrong results.

AddOn:
The real problem I am trying to solve is to have a detail panel with my own reflection system, which could allow me do something like this. It works for most common types, and nested class.

```
{
    if (field.Type == "int") {
        int location[1];
        auto& value = *(int*)((size_t)&Component + Offset + field.Offset);
        memcpy(location, &value, sizeof(location));
        if (ImGui::DragInt(fieldName.c_str(), location, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, "%.1f"))
        {
            memcpy(&value, location, sizeof(location));
        }
    }
    else if (field.Type == "std::string") {
        char buffer[256];
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        auto& value = *(std::string*)((size_t)&Component+ Offset + field.Offset);
        strcpy(buffer, value.c_str());
        if (ImGui::InputText(fieldName.c_str(), buffer, sizeof(buffer))) {
            value = std::string(buffer);
        }
    }
    else if (field.Type == "bool") {
        bool location[1];
        auto& value = *(bool*)((size_t)&Component + Offset + field.Offset);
        memcpy(location, &value, sizeof(location));
        if (ImGui::Checkbox(fieldName.c_str(), location)) {
            memcpy(&value, location, sizeof(location));
        }
    }
    else if (field.Type == "float") {
        float location[1];
        auto& value = *(float*)((size_t)&Component + Offset + field.Offset);
        memcpy(location, &value, sizeof(location));
        if (ImGui::DragFloat(fieldName.c_str(), location, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, "%.1f"))
        {
            memcpy(&value, location, sizeof(location));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not just that `std::vector` simply doesn't work the way you want it to work, it's several core fundamentals of C++ that are at issue here, namely what dynamic scoping it, how it works, and how to use it. What is the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about obtaining the addresses of the values in a vector, given only the address of the vector itself, but the real problem to which you believe that's the solution so that's what you're asking about.

Comment: FYI, vectors are dynamic.  If the vector resizes, shrinks or expands, the array may not be in the exact same place and your pointers will be invalid.  This could be an X-Y problem.

Comment: `&vec.front()` and `&vec.back()` ?

Comment: `std::vector<FTestData>* TestData = (std::vector<FTestData>*)((size_t)&Test);` looks like a train wreck.

Comment: _"not by calling any build-in method of the std::vector function eg [0], .front()"_ - I don't understand the reason you give for not using the member functions. Without them, you are lost.

Comment: The real problem I am trying to solve is to have a detail panel with my own reflection system, which could allow me save my life writing details panel for all kinds of member variable of a class. I made some example updates on the main post

Comment: @Jerry *The real problem I am trying to solve is to have a detail panel with my own reflection system, which could allow me save my life writing details panel for all kinds of member variable of a class.* -- Sounds like a job for template, template specialization, etc., and not what you are attempting to do as your solution.

Comment: `&vec.front()` -- You now have the address of the first item in the vector.  `&vec.back()` -- You now have the address of the last item in the vector.  To be honest, I don't see why these cannot be used as the starting point to whatever you are trying to solve.

Comment: the vector could be implemented with first, capacity and size rather than with pointers

Comment: `memcpy` for C++ objects - ouch.

Answer (score 1):

> To me, a vector layout looks something like this:

You are making an *assumption* about something that is an *implementation detail*.  Your compiler's particular implementation of `std::vector` might work this way (look inside of `<vector>` for yourself), but different implementaions of `std::vector` can lay out and manage their internal members however they want, as long as the public interface behaves how the C++ standard defines it.  You are not even guaranteed that the data members be pointers at all.  There is more than one way to implement a `vector`.

> Is there any way to access the first and last elements in a `std::vector` by its base memory address

No, and trying to do so would be *undefined behavior*.

> I thought the `_First` and `_Last` are right next to the base address, but it keeps outputting the wrong results.

The compiler is free to order class data members however it wants, insert padding between data members, etc.  So you simply can't make the kinds of assumptions you are trying to make.

> The real problem I am trying to solve is to have a detail panel with my own reflection system, which could allow me do something like this. It works for most common types, and nested class.

There are 3rd-party reflection libraries available for C++, you should consider using one of them instead of writing your own from scratch.

That being said, the code you have shown can be simplified a bit, eg:

```
{
    auto* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Component) + Offset + field.Offset;

    if (field.Type == "int") {
        auto& value = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(ptr);
        int temp = value;
        if (ImGui::DragInt(fieldName.c_str(), &temp, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, "%.1f")) {
            value = temp;
        }
    }
    else if (field.Type == "std::string") {
        auto& value = *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(ptr);
        /* see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69046648/
           for how to get rid of this char[] buffer and use
           ImGui::InputText() with std::string directly...

        std::string temp = value;
        if (ImGui::InputText(fieldName.c_str(), &temp) {
            value = temp;
        }
        */

        char buffer[256] = {};
        strncpy(buffer, value.c_str(), std::size(buffer));
        if (ImGui::InputText(fieldName.c_str(), buffer, std::size(buffer))) {
            value = buffer;
        }
    }
    else if (field.Type == "bool") {
        auto& value = *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(ptr);
        bool temp = value;
        if (ImGui::Checkbox(fieldName.c_str(), &temp)) {
            value = temp;
        }
    }
    else if (field.Type == "float") {
        auto& value = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(ptr);
        float temp = value;
        if (ImGui::DragFloat(fieldName.c_str(), &temp, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, "%.1f")) {
            value = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

And then cleaned up a bit further:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void getUiInput(const std::string&, T& t) { }

template<>
void getUiInput<int>(const std::string& fieldName, int& value) {
    int temp = value;
    if (ImGui::DragInt(fieldName.c_str(), &temp, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, "%.1f")) {
        value = temp;
    }
}

template<>
void getUiInput<bool>(const std::string& fieldName, bool& value) {
    bool temp = value;
    if (ImGui::Checkbox(fieldName.c_str(), &temp)) {
        value = temp;
    }
}

template<>
void getUiInput<float>(const std::string& fieldName, float& value) {
    float temp = *value;
    if (ImGui::DragFloat(fieldName.c_str(), &temp, 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, "%.1f")) {
        value = temp;
    }
}

template<>
void getUiInput<std::string>(const std::string& fieldName, std::string& value) {
    /* see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69046648/
       for how to get rid of this char[] buffer and use
       ImGui::InputText() with std::string directly...

    std::string temp = value;
    if (ImGui::InputText(fieldName.c_str(), &temp )) {
        value = temp;
    }
    */

    char buffer[256] = {};
    strncpy(buffer, value.c_str(), std::size(buffer));
    if (ImGui::InputText(fieldName.c_str(), buffer, IM_ARRAYSIZE(buf))) {
        value = buffer;
    }
}

{
    auto* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Component) + Offset + field.Offset;

    if (field.Type == "int") {
        getUiInput(fieldName, *reinterpret_cast<int*>(ptr));
    }
    else if (field.Type == "std::string") {
        getUiInput(fieldName, *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(ptr));
    }
    else if (field.Type == "bool") {
        getUiInput(fieldName, *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(ptr));
    }
    else if (field.Type == "float") {
        getUiInput(fieldName, *reinterpret_cast<float*>(ptr));
    }
}
```